# How can i create table using Docxptl in Python?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx, docxtpl

I want to create a table using docxtpl in python, where the table rows should be dynamic

For eg:

```
user_dict = [{"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"},
         {"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"},
         {"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"},
         {"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"}]
```

if the length of list is n table should dynamically populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output after I was going through the documentation of Docxtpl and tried using list of dictionary

### To create a table with Docxtpl in python

[Sample jinja template format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQMAE.png)

```
    from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

user_dict = [{"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"},
             {"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"},
             {"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"},
             {"name": "Person 1", "age": 25, "job": "Software Engineer"}]

doc = DocxTemplate("dynamic_table_tpl.docx")
context = {'user_record': user_dict}
context.update(context)
doc.render(context)
doc.save(f"user.docx")
```

[Out of the above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3chK.png)

#python #docxtpl